# Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Background-Image inside Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How i can modify `#bg` image so it would be responsive, resizable and proportional in all browser?

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>

            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 well" id="bg">

               </div>

            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
@import url('bootstrap.min.css');

body{
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 12%;    
}

#bg{
    background:url('../img/con_bg4.png') no-repeat center center;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution you were looking for, but according to the bootstrap documentation: "Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element."

Comment: sure i can add img-responsive calss to the <img> but this one is background image. thanks Nick

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

Comment: @redshift Can you please provide the stats you're basing that on, because in every metric I look at IE8 percentage market share is in single figures.

Comment: Disregard @redshift comment - ie8 is no longer a very large demo :) http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-january-2016-12-month-review/

Answer (score 23):

You might also try:

```
background-size: cover;
```

There are some good articles to read about using this CSS3 property: P[erfect Full Page Background Image by CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) and [CSS Background-Size by David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/background-size).

PLEASE NOTE - This will not work with IE8-. However, it will work on most versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 7):

Try this (apply to a class you image is in (not img itself), e.g.

```
.myimage {
  background: transparent url("yourimage.png") no-repeat top center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar issue and i solved it using:

```
background:url(images/banner1.png) no-repeat center top scroll;
background-size: 100% auto;
padding-bottom: 50%;
```

...
here i had to add the **padding: 50%** because it wasn't working for me otherwise. It allowed me to set the height of container, *as per the size ratio of my banner image*. and it is also responsive in my case.

Comment: thank brad, I used this:
`background:#ddd url('../bg-header.png') no-repeat center top scroll;
 background-size: 100% cover;`

Comment: Tried several solutions, this is the first one that worked.

Comment: "background-size: 100% cover" -- Invalid property value

Answer (score 6):

I believe this should also do the job too:

`background-size: contain;`

It specifies that the image should be resized to fit within the element without losing it's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is by using background-size so in your case:

```
background-size: 50% 50%;
```

or

You can set the width and the height of the elements to percentages as well

Comment: thanks for your comment.  i have try background-size, but not works.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
background: url("youimage.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
 background-size: 100% auto;
```

Comment: This works. As your page gets smaller so does the background image. You may need to adjust the % to fit how you like, but ultimately it works. as well you do not need to us the background settings in this example. You can use something like background: url('yourimage') left 190px no-repeat; and it will still work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use fixed:

```
.myimage {
   background:url(admin-user-bg.png) no-repeat top center;
   background: transparent url("yourimage.png") no-repeat top center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: 100%;
   height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mby bootstrap `img-responsive` class is you looking for.