# Bootstrap banner doesn't resize when going to mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a boostrap website and this is the top banner on my site. Basically have a background image that goes 100% across the screen. I have text and a button on the left hand side. 
- It looks fine on desktop, but when I go down to tablet the words go across the persons face on the right hand of the image
- On mobile it doesn't show the persons face

The background image isn't scaling. How do I make it do that?

Tablet screenshot: http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/tabelts-banner.jpg

Mobile screenshot: http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/mobile-banner.jpg

Bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/JeOg9KYYnY

HTML:

```
    <div class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="intro-message">
                    <h1>Adobe Exchange</h1><br>
                    <p class="subtitle">Search the most comprehensive online library of video tutorials, code samples to help you quickly learn how to create the web.</p>
                    <p class="intro-divider"></p>
                     <a href="#register" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span>Register for a Free Account</span></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.intro-header -->
```

CSS:

```
    .intro-header {
    padding-top: 50px; /* If you're making other pages, make sure there is 50px of padding to make sure the navbar doesn't overlap content! */
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background: url(http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/example-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the background image is centered, so on mobile, only the center of the image is visible.

One possible way to do this is to write a media query for mobile/tablet screen sizes, and change the background properties to

```
.intro-header {
    background: url(URL-HERE) no-repeat center right;
}
```

This will right-align the background image.

If you want more finite control of the positioning, you'll probably have to get away from the background property, and use some other tricks. Take a look at this CSS-Tricks article on some different methods for placing background images. The article focuses on full-page backgrounds, but you should be able to apply the methods used to your case.

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

as per [Twitter Bootstrap Responsive Background-Image inside Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055811/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-background-image-inside-div)

Comment: It make the image smaller and fit in the mobile screen, but it's not tall enough and the text goes off the banner

Comment: Yea the proportions of the full banner scaling will throw off the design if you don't scale the rest of the site. You can use media queries (google bootstrap media queries) to make it all fit, but you will likely have to use a different image (or that image cropped) if you want that one to work exactly how you're picturing it.

Comment: How would you fix it then?