# How to create responsive wallpaper ad in Bootstrap 3/4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to add wallpaper ads to a website which look like something given on the image. I have tried using background-size:100% auto based the similar question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055811/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-background-image-inside-div), I've even tried putting a container inside a container-fluid but the layout just doesn't fit. The requirement is to have an image floating to the content until the with is smaller than 991 and the layout changes. I know some other frameworks have classes for this but I just can't make it work.

[image: 1]]

Examples of what I've tried:

This works only on very large screens.

```
html, body {
  background:url(images/static/rollup_web.png) no-repeat center center   fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

<div class="container">
   @yield('content')
</div>
```

This produces almost the same effect as the previous code:

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

This is quite a hack, I get results which are okay but the images are too small, if I expand the left and right columns than my content is shrieked too much:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <!--Left Image of the wallpaper --> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      @yield('content')
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <!--Right Image of the wallpaper --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have examples of the HTML/CSS code you used?

Comment: I have added code examples, even though I've clearly stated two concepts which I used in trying to solve this problem. Don't really see the point of down voting the question because of it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds gets a similar problem I've managed to solve it without breaking Bootstrap grid and with few lines of CSS. The solution requires to have a prepared image in Photoshop where the middle of the image is actually the blank space with the width of the container, 1126px. Put the image outside of the container

```
<div class="wallpaper-ad"> </div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row"> 
      <!-- Content goes here --> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

And the style for this is:

```
.wallpaper-ad {

    background: url(../images/static/image.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
    height:1300px; /* Depends on the image */
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -999;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:991px) { 
    .wallpaper-ad {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery libraries like [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)
They are powerful enough to have a cool responsive image on background for any screen